# SharePoint 2013 Result Sources - Combining BCS Content Source with SP Content Source - Only See SP Content Source

Tags: 2013, search, bcs, search-scope, result-source

Scenario:

*Content Source 1* : **Standard SharePoint Local Sites**

*Content Source 2* : **BCS Application**

Seek to create 1 Unified Search Result from a Common Result Source..

I have been trying to combine a **BCS Content Source** with the Local SharePoint site Content source in a single Result Source.  However, when I try the Result Source in an Enterprise Search set I only get the Local SharePoint site content source and not the BCS Content Source.  Adding the two result sources in separate Result Sources shows the expected result for each content source respectively.

When setting up the Result Source, I am adding the following Settings and KQL. (I also tried (`ContentSource=BCS` OR `ContentSource=Local sites`..) but got same result of only seeing the Local SharePoint Sites Content Source and not the BCS Content Source.

[image: Result Source Scope]

[image: Result Source Query]

Is there an error in my Syntax? Is there a limitation I'm running into in combining multiple content sources in a result source?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should add that this is on June CU 2013, in case there is a bug anyone is aware of causing this.

Comment: Daniel, I didn't have to do anything to get my BCS results to show on the "Everything" tab. They are included in the Result Source "Local SharePoint Results (System). I am on a slightly earlier build: 15.0.4505.1005 (April 2013) Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reponse Matthew. I will check again if I missed something, was trying to filter out most sharepoint search results and only show a few content types and BCS.

Comment: Hi I have a similar requirement. Did you found any workaround for it?

Comment: can you show me the error detail ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, that's a little different, though still totally possible. Look at the EntityName crawled property, it should contain the name of your BCS Entities. If you make that a managed property it is easy to create rules to specify the exact entities you want like you do with Content Type names.